Teradata SQL question - How do I match one to many column values Using CASE statement with IN and Inner join?
I have a requirement like:
Table2
VehID. VehName   Fuel     Color


Tesla     El        Red



Benz      El        Blue



Tata      Ga        White         



Ins Target Table 3
Sel 
VehID ,
case when
        Fuel in ('El', 'Ga')
    and Color in ('Red', 'Blue' , 'White', 'Black')
     then 'Y'
    else  'N' as BuyInD
From Table2 ;

I need to replace the 'Hard Coding' with a Meta / Look Up table:
Replace hard code with Reference Table :
Lookup Ref/Table: Table1



CarName
FuelType
Color




Tesla
El
Red


Benz
Ga
Blue


Tata
Ga
White


Audi
El
Black



In Target Table 
Sel 
VehID ,
case when
        Fuel = b.FuelType
    and Color = b.Color
     then 'Y'
    else  'N' as BuyInD
From Table2 a,
 Table1 b;

The above join is not right, as the match is against only 1 value instead of all the values in the column.
Thanks Tim for your response.
My Actual SQL is an INS SQL with multiple table joins and having multiple case statements. It's something like:
Sel 
a.VehID ,
b.begin_dte,
b.end_dte,
c.comp_name,
c.comp_addr,
case when a.CarType in ('SUV')
    and    a.Fuel in ('El', 'Ga')
    and a.Color in ('Red', 'Blue' )
     then 'Y'
    when a.CarType in ('SUV')
    and a.FuelMod1 in ('El', 'Ga')
    and a.ColorMod1 in ('Red', 'Blue' ) 
      then 'Y'
    when a.CarType in ('SUV')
    and a.FuelMod2 in ('El', 'Ga')
    and a.ColorMod2 in ('Red', 'Blue' ) 
      then 'Y'
    else  'N' as BuyInD
From Cars a,
    Saledate b, 
    c.comp
where a.VehID = b.VehID
and date between b.begin_dte and b.end_dte
and a.VehID = c.VehID;

Could you pls suggest how can I use the Left join here and match the multiple case statements? Thanks!

You may use a left anti-join approach here:
SELECT
    t2.VehID,
    CASE WHEN t1.CarName IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS BuyInD
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t1.CarName = t2.VehName AND
       t1.FuelType = t2.Fuel AND
       t1.Color = t2.Color;

For vehicles from Table2 which have matching fuel types and colors in the Table1 lookup table, the column t1.CarName will not be null.  Otherwise, for non matching vehicles, this column will be null.

Thanks for your suggestion. My actual SQL is different with multiple table joins and there are multiple case when statements.

I have updated the question with the SQL I'm trying to update. could you please take a look and suggest? Thanks!

I have already provided an answer based on the initial sample data and code.
